# resizeToFitText() leads to text overflowing textbox with non-Latin characters

Tags: java, apache-poi

We're using Apache POI 3.16 (latest version at the time of writing).

Our code looks like this:

```
XSLFTextBox textBox = slide.createTextBox();
XSLFTextParagraph paragraph = textBox.getTextParagraphs().get(0);
XSLFTextRun textRun = paragraph.addNewTextRun();
textRun.setText("non-Latin characters here");
textBox.setAnchor(new Rectangle(left, top, width, 10000));
textBox.resizeToFitText();
```

Note that we are not changing the font style in any way.

This code results in the text overflowing the textbox:

[image: Text overflowing textbox with Apache POI]

It does not appear to be an Apache POI bug. I could find only two issues about `resizeToFitText()` ([Bug 45140](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45140), [Bug 47594](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47594)) and both are related to newline characters ([which is another problem we're encountering](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45140)).

Any idea on how we could circumvent the problem?

UPDATE 1: Here is a complete, standalone repro case:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextBox;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextRun;

public class TextBoxOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();

        XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.createSlide();

        XSLFTextBox textBox = slide.createTextBox();
        XSLFTextParagraph paragraph = textBox.getTextParagraphs().get(0);
        XSLFTextRun textRun = paragraph.addNewTextRun();
        textRun.setText(
            "ちょっと早いけどTシャツが着たくなる季節♡お母さんの影響か、非常に恐竜が大好きです。もう飼いたいくらい大好きです。#ジュラシックワールド のラプトル4姉妹とか激的に可愛くて可愛くて可愛くて可愛いです。めろめろ、大好き♡お母さんも恐竜が好きで、小さい頃、古代生物の図鑑を一緒に見てたの思い出す〜とい");
        textBox.setAnchor(new Rectangle(50, 50, 200, 5000));
        textBox.resizeToFitText();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("TextBoxOverflow.pptx");
        slideShow.write(out);
        out.close();
        slideShow.close();
    }
}
```

and the result:

[image: Text overflowing textbox with Apache POI]

UPDATE 2: Bug logged in Apache POI's bug tracker:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61169

Comment: What language this will be? Works for me using Japanese and Chinese. Overflows a little bit using Indian. And totally fails using languages with other text directions like Arab and Hebrew. But for those the box is **longer** as the text. Please show complete example to reproduce this exactly behavior.

Comment: @AxelRichter This appears to be Japanese. We're cooking up a standalone repro case.

Comment: @AxelRichter I updated my question with code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a disadvantage of the poor Unicode support of `Windows` until now.

If I run the following code

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextBox;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextRun;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.CTShape;

public class TextBoxOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();

        XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.createSlide();

        XSLFTextBox textBox = slide.createTextBox();
        XSLFTextParagraph paragraph = textBox.getTextParagraphs().get(0);
        XSLFTextRun textRun = paragraph.addNewTextRun();

        textRun.setText(
            "ちょっと早いけどTシャツが着たくなる季節♡お母さんの影響か、非常に恐竜が大好きです。もう飼いたいくらい大好きです。#ジュラシックワールド のラプトル4姉妹とか激的に可愛くて可愛くて可愛くて可愛いです。めろめろ、大好き♡お母さんも恐竜が好きで、小さい頃、古代生物の図鑑を一緒に見てたの思い出す〜とい");

        textBox.setAnchor(new Rectangle(50, 50, 200, 5000));

        double heigth = textBox.getTextHeight();
System.out.println(heigth);

        textBox.resizeToFitText();

        CTShape ctshape = (CTShape)textBox.getXmlObject();
System.out.println(ctshape.getSpPr());

        //set TextBox autofit the text 
        ctshape.getTxBody().getBodyPr().addNewSpAutoFit();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("TextBoxOverflow.pptx");
        slideShow.write(out);
        out.close();
        slideShow.close();
    }
}
```

in `Linux` then I get:

[image]

As you see the `textBox.getTextHeight()` is `330.0` and the `cy` in the anchor is `cy="4203700"`.

This leads to a proper resized text box.

If I do the same in `Windows`, then I get:

[image]

As you see the `textBox.getTextHeight()` is `183.78125` and the `cy` in the anchor is `cy="2346722"`.

And this surely leads to a text box in only half the height.

If you do `ctshape.getTxBody().getBodyPr().addNewSpAutoFit();` then the "autofit the text box size to the text" flag is set. Then at least any changing on the text in PowerPoint will lead to autofit the box.

---

Edit Jun 10 2017:

Found at least an approximate solution. If we set the font family of the `XSLFTextRun` to "Meiryo", then the determination of the text box height is approximately correct also in `Windows`:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextBox;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextRun;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.presentationml.x2006.main.CTShape;

public class TextBoxOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();

        XSLFSlide slide = slideShow.createSlide();

        XSLFTextBox textBox = slide.createTextBox();
        XSLFTextParagraph paragraph = textBox.getTextParagraphs().get(0);
        XSLFTextRun textRun = paragraph.addNewTextRun();

        String fontfamily = "Meiryo";
        textRun.setFontFamily(fontfamily);  

        textRun.setText(
            "ちょっと早いけどTシャツが着たくなる季節♡お母さんの影響か、非常に恐竜が大好きです。もう飼いたいくらい大好きです。#ジュラシックワールド のラプトル4姉妹とか激的に可愛くて可愛くて可愛くて可愛いです。めろめろ、大好き♡お母さんも恐竜が好きで、小さい頃、古代生物の図鑑を一緒に見てたの思い出す〜とい");

        textBox.setAnchor(new Rectangle(50, 50, 200, 5000));

        double heigth = textBox.getTextHeight();
System.out.println(heigth);

        textBox.resizeToFitText();

        CTShape ctshape = (CTShape)textBox.getXmlObject();
System.out.println(ctshape.getSpPr());

        //set TextBox autofit the text 
        ctshape.getTxBody().getBodyPr().addNewSpAutoFit();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("TextBoxOverflow.pptx");
        slideShow.write(out);
        out.close();
        slideShow.close();
    }
}
```

Leads in `Linux`to the same values as above: The `textBox.getTextHeight()` is `330.0` and the `cy` in the anchor is `cy="4203700"`.

But now in `Windows` the `textBox.getTextHeight()` is `353.8330078125` and the `cy` in the anchor is `cy="4506379"`. In combination with `ctshape.getTxBody().getBodyPr().addNewSpAutoFit();`this is acceptable in my opinion.

Not clear who to blame for this. Either `Microsoft` because of its poor Unicode support or `Java` because of its poor font management.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer! FWIW, we're running our production code on AWS Lambda (i.e. [Amazon Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html)). We've ran your test program there and we're getting 2806700 for `cy`. Regarding your edit with a workaround: this is an interesting solution; we would probably need to change font based on the dominant character set of the string... To be investigated. Thanks again!